# fear of sin while reciting the holy Quran

Tags: quran, tajweed

i am non-native Arabic speakers, perfecting the sounds of some letters and words of Arabic can be very difficult. However, i am trying my best to master Tajweed but if i know that i am pronouncing some words not perfect in sound?is this a sin for me while reciting or not.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamStackExchange the Q&A site about Islam. Take our [tour] and check our [help] for further information.

Comment: So what kinds of efforts do you do to "perfect" the Qur'an recitation? Would you mind adding some more Information by using the **edit** link at the bottom of your post?